# Is there a custom WCF binding for Remote Desktop Services (RDS) Dynamic Virtual Channels?

Tags: .net, wcf, remote-desktop, rdp, virtual-channel

I would like to use RDS (Remote Desktop Services) Dynamic Virtual Channels in my code. There are some samples on the net how to do the raw communication over virtual channels and even a library for .NET (RDPAddins.NET) but I was wondering if there is already a ready made WCF custom binding for Dynamic Virtual Channels?

[1] [RDPAddins.NET](http://rdpaddins.codeplex.com/)

[2] [How to write Terminal Services Add-In in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16374/How-to-Write-a-Terminal-Services-Add-in-in-Pure-C)